# How do I make this ridge above my front door look great?

Tags: doors, paint, render

Through the years this ridge above my front door has really taken a battering. Looks really untidy now.

How would I go back restoring this best, what’s likely causing it to erode and how could I prevent it? Any suggestions to make it look great are much appreciated. The symmetrical semi detached has a small roof but looking at quicker options for the time being as I suspect that roof would cost a few thousand (have included next doors at the last photo)

[[image]] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA83v.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Appears to need a wire-brushing or scraping and a fresh coat of paint, at minimum.

Assuming you have "aluminium flake roofing paint" (sometimes described as "patch" rather than paint) locally available, that would be the most durable paint option that comes to mind. I would not say it looks the best, though, as compared to non-paint options given below. But it's *functional* if reapplied as needed.

What's causing it to erode is being a roof, with what does not appear to be a suitable roofing surface on it (certainly looks like just paint, or "render" and paint, like the walls, from here.) So it gets rained and snowed on and hasn't got the durability for that service in the surface material. So it's damp and appears to be growing lichen.

Could also flash the whole thing with metal (copper, aluminium, lead - as you prefer) for a more weather-durable surface without trying to keep up with the neighbor's example.

Comment: A model train set running on it is optional, but *would* be fun....

Comment: Copper would look nice and would double as flashing if you do it properly.  You'll need to [remove and replace](https://www.diynot.com/diy/threads/how-to-fix-flashing-to-a-pebbledash-wall.3912/) some of the pebble dash on the wall.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start out by pressure cleaning the whole ridge, followed by a good scraping. Then get some epoxy concrete paint and finish it off. The paint comes in a variety of colors. You might want to consider having gutters installed on the edges to keep the water from drenching anyone coming and going.